# Need to have different auth source for one SP

Tags: simplesamlphp

I have set up a SimpleSAMLPHP IdP, making use of LDAP as my primary auth source, which is successfully being used by about 8 SPs.  I need to add another SP, but this one needs to use a different auth source.  Any suggestions on how to do this?  Specifically, the auth source I need is to the same LDAP server, but users for this new SP need to have membership in a different LDAP group.  I have set up an additional entry in the authsource.php file, but I can't figure out how to point the single SP at that new auth source.

Any suggestions?  I'd like to avoid having to set up a separate IdP, if at all possible.